# Can't ping anything when IPV6 is disabled

Tags: debian, networking, ip, ipv6, sysctl

When I disable IPV6 on my Debian install I can't reach the internet, and whenever I ping anything I get `ping: unknown host ...`

This is how I am currently disabling IPV6

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

in my `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: Please add more details, including exactly what it falls and possible logs. The post is rather too vague as it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of this problem was that in my `/etc/resolv.conf` I had `domain hsd1.XX.comcast.net` as the first entry which was IPV6, and so I had no DNS. I fixed the problem by simply commenting that line out with a #.

Comment: This answer makes no sense.  Changing the DNS client library's search path does not cut off DNS service.  It merely makes the client ask different sequences of questions.